# Qtcreator.exe missing from Qt 4.7.3

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator

Hi I have recently downloaded qt 4.7.3 for windows **qt-win-opensource-4.7.3-vs2008.exe** from this [Link](http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.7/)  , I was using **Qt Creator 3.0.1 based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)** till now , but I need to build my project in **Qt 4.7.3** ...the problem is **I couldn't find the Qtcreator.exe** in the downloaded folder , it contains all the libraries and everything except the.exe file .**Is there any solution to get the Qtcreator.exe file for Qt 4.7.3 or is there any way to configure it with my Qt creator 3.0.1?**

Comment: Add your qt version in options of QtCreator: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.5/creator-project-qmake.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt 4.7.3 is quite old, back at this time it was shipped in the Nokia SDK along with the Qt version.

There is no reason why you can't add Qt 4.7.3 as a Qt version in your existing copy of Qt Creator 3.0.1 you should only need 1 copy of Qt Creator on your machine.

- In QtCreator go to Tools->Options->Build&Run->Qt Versions
- Click the add button and navigate to qmake for Qt 4.7.3
- This should have created a kit for 4.7.3
- You should now be able to go back to the projects tab for your project add the Qt 4.7.3 kit and build your project with 4.7.3

Comment: Thanks buddy, I have already tried out these steps , and I was missing MS VS 2008 compiler, I was using 2010 compiler . Have a good day :)